# .NET List.Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, extension-methods

I'm using .NET 3.5. Why am I still be getting:

> does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'

with this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

       //.. . . . . code


    List<string> Words = new List<string>();
       // many strings added here . . .
    Words = Words.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Are you

```
using System.Linq;
```

?

`Distinct` is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable` so you need to add that using statement.

And don't forget to add a reference to `System.Core.dll` (if you're using VS2008, this has already been done for you).

Comment: Is there a reason for naming it like that?

Comment: Martinho -- naming _what_ like _what_?

Comment: System.Core. It's mainly extensions... So why Core?

Comment: Ah. No particularly good reason that I'm aware of. What would you have named it?

Comment: I'm not very good at names, but I think Core is counter-intuitive, since there are a lot of extensions in there. It's not really that important, though. I was just curious about it.

Comment: I would imagine that "Core" here means "something that should really be in mscorlib, but we couldn't put it there for backcompat reasons" :)

Comment: @Pavel: That sounds more like it.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

`Distinct` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that is defined in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx), so you can only call it if you import that namespace.

You'll also need to add a reference to `System.Core.dll`.
If you created the project as a .Net 3.5 project, it will already be referenced; if you upgraded it from .Net 2 or 3, you'll have to add the reference yourself.

Answer (score 2):

From msdn blog: Charlie Calvert [MSDN Blog Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2008/07/12/linq-farm-more-on-set-operators/)

To use on [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) :
--project type: Console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var listA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 };
        var listB = listA.Distinct();

        foreach (var item in listB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
// output: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 List<string> words  = new List<string>();

 // many strings added here . . .

 IEnumerable <string> distinctword  =Words .distinct();

 foreach(string index in distinctword )
 {
      // do what u want here . . .
 }
```

Comment: Providing a fix does not answer question "Why".