# Extension Methods not Recognized

Tags: c#, extension-methods

What is necessary to have an extension method honored when it exists in an imported assembly?  I built one in a class library project but it is not recognized in my web project which references the library.  All the other classes and methods in the library are honored and visible but this extension method is not. The extension method is visible when used within the library.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138848/net-list-distinct

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Referencing an assembly containing a class with extension methods is not enough. You need to import the namespace containing the class in each of your source file where you want to use the extension methods.

For example, to use LINQ-to-objects, you need to reference the **System.Core assembly** and import the **System.Linq namespace** (which contains the Enumerable class with the LINQ extension methods):

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I have Using statements in my class files that reference the library and my project already references it.  Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Are your extension method and the class containing the method public? Have you double-checked that you didn't forget `this` in the method signature? Does it work if you don't use extension method syntax to call the method?

Comment: You need to find out what namespace the extension class you want is implemented in, and use that namespace in the C# code where you want the extensions available.  You have to be very specific.

Comment: yes i can see the extension method when NOT using the extension method syntax.  The namespace containing the extension method is the same as all other methods in my library.  The class and extension method is marked as "public static" and yes "this" is included in the method signature.

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: This there was some type of Visual Studio referencing problem between projects.  Deleted and restored references and it cleared up...

Comment: Just closed and reopened Visual Studio and it is appeared.

Comment: @dtb, Ha! my extension class was static but not public. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

If the Extension method is callable when not using the Extension syntax, use the Format:

```
this.MyExtensionMethod()
```

That cleared up my problem of not finding the Extension method of a class in VS2010.

Comment: @IanKemp It’s still cleaner syntax than `MyExtensionMethodsClass.MyExtensionMethod(this)` and allows you to swap out implementations by replacing your `using`. It’s sort of a sort of decoupling/dependency injection.

Comment: @binki That seems like the least intuitive and useful way of doing DI that I could possibly imagine.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Import is not a problem. this keyword is sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 19):

Are you sure the extension method is made public?

Comment: yes the class is marked public static as it the extension method.

Comment: My issue was that the extension method was public but the class was not. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who lands here while having the same problem in VB.NET, note that not only the extension method, but the **module itself needs to be marked as `Public`** or else you'll get this error. This is the case at least with VS2015 Community and will likely be the case in other versions too.

Comment: This is true for C# as well: The static class needs to be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if using templates, your template declaration matches what is declared in the method signature with, "this"..

So,

```
SomeClass<string, string> test = new SomeClass<string, string>();

extensionMethod<key, val>(this SomeClass<key, Lazy<val>>, string val)
{
}
```

the extension method will not show up because of the lazy wrapper.

Comment: Not sure what the -1 is for, but this was my issue and didn't notice it right away as I changed the type in the extension and forgot to do it on the declaration and the compiler showed no problems.  

Maybe it's because I said templates accidentally rather than generics. but the point was made.

Answer (score 0):

For an example implementation that helped me:

(Note the `this` keyword that has already been mentioned).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert current bytes to string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">Current byte[]</param>
    /// <returns>String version of current bytes</returns>
    public static string StringValue(this byte[] currentBytes)
    {
        return string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(bytes, b => b.ToString("X2")));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I had this same problem none of the answers worked. Turns out it was because the `using` statement of the assembly was aliased:

```
using ex = MyApp.Example
```

Removing the alias worked, but I decided instead to add a duplicate, non-aliased `using`, which also fixed the problem:

```
using MyApp.Example
using ex = MyApp.Example
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using an extension method on enums in solutions referenced each other as shown below.  Intellisense worked for the extension method in the ApplicationUI project and it even ran without compile or run-time errors.  But the method simply didn't work.  Also, the immediate window assured me that BusinessObjectLib.MyEnum did not contain a method with the name of my extension method, and no extension method could be found.

```
GenericLib - project where extension method on generic enums is defined
BusinessObjectLib - project where enums were defined, references GenericLib
ApplicationUI - project referencing both GenericLib and BusinessObjectLib
```

Even though, the Solution Explorer looked OK viewing all projects from ApplicationUI, when I opened the BusinessObjectLib project, I could see its reference to GenericLib was broken for some reason.  (Like all of our code, VS probably has bugs as well?).  First, I worked in the BusinessObjectLib project opened directly in VS, removing the ref, then removing the project, then restoring both in the opposite order.  Then I renamed the ApplicationUI.sou file and forced it to be rebuilt. I was able to fix this  problem through these actions, but only the .sou file rename seemed to do the trick.  The immediate window **still** continues to give me the same error, but at least the run-time code works again.  I am using this exact pattern in several other projects without having the kind of problem I'm having here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Extension method was in an external reference which was referencing a different version of a component. I synchronized versions on both projects and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about method signature

public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomizedLogging(this ILoggingBuilder builder, string appInsightsKey)

"this" modifier is required for extension methods

Answer (score 0):

Look out for dynamic types.

There are many answer, and none of them solved my problem, in case someone else faces this, my case the third party library was returning a "`dynamic`" type and my extension method was working over strings, so when applying the extension method, did not show a compilation error, but during runing time, it did.

```
var a = thirdpartyLibrary.GetValue().MyExtensionMethod();
```

A cast to the same type of my extension method solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it said the reason the method was not recognized had nothing to do with extension methods, but an error in the same file which did not show up in the IDE - For me the solution was restarting the IDE and it suddenly displayed the actual error i had to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues that stemmed from the following solution structure:

- .csproj A had an extension method class, `MyExtesntion.cs`.
- .csproj B had a reference to A, *together* with a linked file linking to `MyExtesntion.cs`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265331/3002584) helped me pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### If consuming an extension method in VB.NET

I was working with some code where `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` were both off.

```vb
   Option Strict Off
   Option Infer Off
   Imports ExtensionsClass

...

   Dim dt1 = GetDataTable()

   ' YES: this works
   Dim dt2 As DataTable =
       ExtensionsClass.ExtentionMethod(dt1, "parameter1", "parameter2")

   ' NO: this fails
   Dim dt3 As DataTable =
       dt1.ExtentionMethod( "parameter1", "parameter2")
```

### Reason why it failed

In the line `Dim dt1 = GetDataTable()`, `dt1` is being declared as an `Object`. VB.NET will compile the code even though there is no method `ExtentionMethod` on type `Object`.

### Solution

Either turn `Option Infer On`, which will cause `dt1` to be interpreted as a `DataTable` from the signature of the `GetDataTable` method.

or do not use type inference, but rather, manually define your variable types

`Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetDataTable()`

### Observations

VS2015 did not red-underline the failing code.

`Dim dt3 As DataTable = dt1.ExtentionMethod( "parameter1", "parameter2")`

But if I tried to F12 (Go To Definition), the IDE would give me the "cannot navigate to symbol..." error.

I didn't find the error until a user reported it.