# Extension method marked as ambiguous

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble with extension methods. Another method was causing the same error, now I am having the same issue again. While compiling - visual studio is marking my extension method as ambiguous. But I am pretty sure this is the only implementation I have -

The extension method I have is -

```
public static class TypeInfoExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="types">The types.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetPropertyDictionaryList<T>(this IEnumerable<TypeInfo> types) where T : Attribute
    {
        return types.Select(x => x.GetPropertyDictionary<T>());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, object> GetPropertyDictionary<T>(this TypeInfo type) where T : Attribute
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        return dict;
    }
}
```

And it is used like this -

```
var model = ...... // other codes

var parameters = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Model.Domain.Tenants.Tenant)).DefinedTypes;
model.AvailableProperties = parameters.GetPropertyDictionaryList<MessageTemplateItem>().ToList()
```

This is the only implementation I have, I just added it, but VS is showing this error -

> Error 81  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'SMP.Core.Extensions.TypeInfoExtensions.GetPropertyDictionary(System.Reflection.TypeInfo)'
>   and
>   'SMP.Core.Extensions.TypeInfoExtensions.GetPropertyDictionary(System.Reflection.TypeInfo)'

I am thinking this might be a temporary error, may be cleaning the solution is not cleaning references or cache. But if any body else have faced this error, I would very much appreciate your feedback.

**UPDATE** Strangely enough this code works -

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetPropertyDictionaryList<T>(this IEnumerable<TypeInfo> types) where T : Attribute
{
    return types.Select(x => GetPropertyDictionary<T>(x));
}
```

I am really confused now, so far I knew these are the same for an extension method -

```
GetPropertyDictionary<T>(x)
x.GetPropertyDictionary<T>()
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Restart VS and see if it disappears

Comment: I have had issues with using extension methods with dynamic types.  Instead of using "var parameters = "  use the actual type and see if that solves the issue for you.

Comment: I compiled your code and it is working fine. Try deleting all the dlls from bin and obj folders and see if it works.

Comment: @ELewis I don't think that could be a problem. It calls succesfully, it is the second call inside that method, causing the problem.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I tried restarting VS a couple of times, still causing issue.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: I guess that you have another copy of your extension method somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had declared an extension method in project A. While using it in this project worked, it would not work in another project B. There it was marked as being ambiguous. Calling it in a static way in project B worked however.

When searching by string in the whole solution or reference, I could not find any additional implementation to the one in project A.

The problem finally was: I accidentally added a link of the source file of the extension method from project A into project B. Removing the link to the source file in project B solved the problem.

Comment: Please comment the down-vote, I would like to improve the answer if something is wrong or not understandable, but this is only possible if I get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across the same issue. If it wasn't for source control I'd never have tracked it down.

The project had been using extension methods just fine for a number of years. Then, after some changes *all* the uses of extension methods started coming up as:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: ...

Both items called out had exactly the same namespace and signature.

A diff on the `csproj` file revealed the problem. The output executable from the `obj` directory had somehow been added as a reference in the hint path.

Something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="OutputExecutable">
        <HintPath>obj\DEBUG\OutputExecutable.exe</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Removing that erroneous entry got everything building again. How it got there in the first place is currently a mystery.